# Need To Trap No CGSize on Occasional Nil values in IOS Building a PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, null, cgsize

I am creating 2 columns down a page.  The left column is the "Label", the Right column is the "Data".  I'm building and getting the CGSize on the "Data" side because it may wrap down considerably.  The "Label" side is pre-configure text and is written after the data.

But the problem comes in if there is no data in an object (nil?).  Then the next data write does not get moved down.  And the next "Label" get's over written.  Here is my code.  It repeats for about 20 different attributes.

Thanks in advance.  I'm just looking for the cleanest way to #1 check for no "size" (no data was entered by the user), and/or #2 assign a minimum 'size'.  here is the code that essentially is going on ..

```
size = [[self.currentLoad otherTrailers] sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxDataWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[[self.currentLoad otherTrailers]drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin+maxLabelWidth+kColumnMargin, currentPageY, maxDataWidth, maxHeight) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[@"Other Trailers" drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY, maxLabelWidth, maxHeight) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
currentPageY += size.height;
```

Comment: That's part of the problem too, I'm not sure what I should set the height for to at least accommodate for the Label to the left without then having to set on that object.  I really don't want to have to iterate through a whole series of if/else statements but I may have to, but maybe somewhere else to set a return value to @" ".  Is a system font height always going to equal it's "size"?

Answer (score 0):

Get and check the value:

```
NSString *value = [self.currentLoad otherTrailers];
CGFloat height = 15; // or some appropriate minimum value
if (value.length) {
    size = [value sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(maxDataWidth, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [value drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin+maxLabelWidth+kColumnMargin, currentPageY, maxDataWidth, maxHeight) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    height = size.height;
}

[@"Other Trailers" drawInRect:CGRectMake(kMargin, currentPageY, maxLabelWidth, maxHeight) withFont:textFont lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
currentPageY += height;
```

Comment: if (size.height == 0) {
        size.height = kMinimumHeight;
    }  // added right before the increment seemed to do the trick and seemed a little easier.  That's the problem with IOS.  Theres a dozen ways to skin the cat and they can still be hard to figure out sometimes for us newbies.